# rails active record grouping with range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, grouping

I have a user model with **quality** field in it. The data type of the field is float.

Now I want to group all the users according to quality range as follows

```
[65 - 75],[75 - 85], [85 - 95] and [95 - 100]
```

Note: I want all users with quality form 65 to 75 in one group and 75- 85 in another group.

How do I achieve this with ActiveRecord.

Thanks

Comment: I want a single query that can group users accordingly to the ranges given above.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use `group` and `having` functions of `ActiveRecord` like this:

```
Model.select(:quality).group(:quality).having("quality > 65 AND quality < 75")
Model.select(:quality).group(:quality).having("quality > 75 AND quality < 85")
Model.select(:quality).group(:quality).having("quality > 85 AND quality < 95")
Model.select(:quality).group(:quality).having("quality > 95 AND quality < 100")
```

Comment: How can I merge all these down to one query?

Comment: Well, if you want to group them in different groups, you can't do just one query.

Answer (score -1):

```
User.where(:quality => (65..75))
User.where(:quality => (75..85))
User.where(:quality => (85..95))
User.where(:quality => (95..100))
```

Or, if you want a single query, you have 3 options:

- Using the string form

  ```
  User.where("(quality >= 65 AND quality <= 75) OR (quality >= 75 AND quality <= 85) OR (quality >= 85 AND quality <= 95) OR (quality >= 95 AND quality <= 100)").group(:quality)
  ```
- Writing the SQL with OR clauses or
- Using the [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel) gem.